# c# dictionary ObjectReference not set

Tags: c#, dictionary

Why does this code return a `NullReferenceExeption` on the first if statement? How should it be remedied?

```
void Main()
{
    addOrIncrement(new KeyValuePair<string,long>("1",1));
    addOrIncrement(new KeyValuePair<string,long>("1",1));
}

public Dictionary<string, long> Result { get; set; }

public void addOrIncrement(KeyValuePair<string,long> pair){
    if(Result.ContainsKey(pair.Key))
    {
        Result[pair.Key] += pair.Value;
    } else {
        Result.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Result` is never initialised, so it's `null`

```
public Dictionary<string, long> Result { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, long>();
```

Should do the trick

Comment: wow,  my head is not working today apparently. How did I miss that?